# Excel using PivotCaches.Create from recorded macro

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to create a pivot table. Using the record macro function I created a small pivot table, however when I try to adjust the code from the recorded macro I get an error (Type mismatch).

The recorded macro looks as follows:

```
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "tadasEquities_20150223133033!R1C1:R780C71", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet52!R3C1", TableName:= _
        "PivotTable32", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet52").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable32").PivotFields("Research type")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
```

This is the part of the code I adjust.

```
        Worksheets("Pivot Table").PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        rngData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Worksheets("Pivot Table").Cells(1, 1), TableName:= _
        "PivotTable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

rngData is defined as:

```
Set wsData = Worksheets(1)
Set rngData = wsData.Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1), Worksheets(1).Cells(downlast, rightlast))
```

Worksheet("Pivot Table") is

```
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Pivot Table"
```

where rightlast and downlast are the last cells of a table.

As you can see I only adjust SourceData and TableDestination and use Worksheets instead of ActiveWorkbook. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the SourceData and TableDestination I used the following two lines. The pivot table works well now.

```
dataSource = Worksheets(1).Name & "!" & Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(downlast, rightlast)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) 'Set the source data, you can make this dynamic if you want
destination = Worksheets(2).Name & "!" & Worksheets(2).Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `SourceData` and `TableDestination` as `String` like this:

```
Worksheets("Pivot Table").PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    rngdata.Address(, , xlR1C1, True), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Worksheets("Pivot Table").Cells(1, 1) _
    .Address(, , xlR1C1, True), TableName:="PivotTable", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

What you did is you are passing `Range Object` on both arguments.
We simply used the `Range Object Address Property` (which returns a string) with reference style set to `R1C1` and external set to `True` to include the worksheet name in the address.
 This compiles but not tested. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, i still get an error: Object does not support this property or method. In addition, the [msdn.microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivotcaches.create%28v=office.14%29.aspx) says that the SourceData can be a Range Object: The SourceData argument is required if SourceType isn't xlExternal. It can be a Range object (when SourceType is either xlConsolidation or xlDatabase) or an Excel WorkbookConnection object (when SourceType is xlExternal).

Comment: @Tadas I just examined the code you've posted which works. In that code, you passed `String` on your arguments. which is the only difference in what you've tried (wherein you passed objects).